# Remove selected class jquery

Tags: jquery, html, class, select, scripting

I've got the following HTML:

```
<a href="#">img/a.jpg</a>
<a href="#">img/b.jpg</a>
<a href="#">img/c.jpg</a>
```

For selected links I've got the following:

```
$(function() {
            $("a").click( function( )
            {
            var current = $(this);
            var name = current.attr('href');
            current.addClass("selected");
            var prev = current.closest("a").find("a.selected");
            prev.removeClass("selected");
                return false;
            });
        });
```

The problem is that after I click some link the previous one I clicked won't deselect(remove class selected). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could remove all elements that have a class of selected first, then apply your selected class to the current one.

```
$("a").click(function( {
    var current = $(this);
    var name = current.attr('href');

    //Remove all
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');

    //Add to current
    current.addClass("selected");

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Good answer, please fix the syntax error. in the first line there is:
function( 
instead of 
function()

Answer (score 4):

you could do:

```
$(function() {
            $("a").click( function( )
            {
            var current = $(this);
            var name = current.attr('href');
            $('a.selected').removeClass('selected');
            current.addClass("selected");

                return false;
            });
        });
```

closest doesn't work in your example because it goes up the DOM tree

Comment: Not only does it go up (as `.parent()` does), it starts with itself. So, the "prev" element will always be itself with a `.closest()` call (at least until it gets to the `.find()` where it then finds no matches and fails).

Answer (score 1):

I'd try the following:

```
$(function() {
     $("a").click( function() {

         //GEt the current element
         var current = $(this);
         var name = current.attr("href");

         //Remove the class from the previous element
         $('.selected').removeClass("selected");

         //Add the class to the current element
         current.addClass("selected");

         //Let's get back to work!
         return false;

    })
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) isn't correct I don't think. Remember that `.closest` looks to itself then up the tree for a match. So, in your case, it's finding itself first then looking (within) itself for an anchor with the selected class applied. (As I read it, your code should be applying and removing the selected class to/from itself.)

You may want to try [`.siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead. That said, I would suggest [the following](http://jsfiddle.net/JSgTR/) instead:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    // store the current anchor
    var $a = $(this);

    // add the selected class to this element
    $a.addClass('selected');

    // look around to links nearby, with the selected class, and remove that class
    $a.siblings('a.selected').removeClass('selected');

    // prevent further action
    e.preventDefault(); return false;
});
```

I feel like using a generic `$('a.selected')` or `$('.selected')` is overly broad and may grab links on the page you don't want. I may be wrong, but this keeps it within the current navigation portion of your page (at least within the same container that all those anchors are within).